# Matrix of int(bytes_read_from_file), python

Tags: python

How can I fill up a matrix with int(bytes) read from file? I tried:

```
import struct
a = []
z = 1
while z <= 8:
    a.append([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    z+=1

file = open("filename.txt", "rb")

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        a[i][j] = struct.unpack("i", file.read(1))
print(a)
```

But i get error, :

```
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

tried to:

```
a[i][j] = struct.unpack("i", file.read(4))
```

But it did nthing. Out put is still:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

I want it to be a matrix of integers so i can do some bitwise operaions later. Any ideas? Sry if its dupicate but i didint find anything helpfull.

Comment: Does your `file.read(4)` return 4 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct (with the line `file.read(4)`), but check your input file.
`file.read(n)` returns **at most** *n* bytes. If your file is too short and is not aligned with 4-byte structures you try to read - you will get the error.